# Can't edit the process template in Process Template Manager

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-process-template

I'm using TFS 2013 and Visual Studio 2012 and I'm trying to edit the process template.
On the following [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181510(v=vs.110).aspx) it says: "You must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group".
Even though my account is in Project Collection Administrators group I cannot download, edit nor upload process template from Visual Studio, as you can see from image below:

[image]

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. For TFS 2013 in order to be able to edit and upload process template, you have to have Visual Studio 2013 installed. VS2012 isn't going to help you up with this. Here is the [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx) and citation:

> To create a team project or manage process templates on an on-premises TFS, you must connect using the same version level of Visual Studio or Team Explorer. That is, to create a team project on TFS 2013, you must connect from Team Explorer 2013.